# post method get value directly in my SQL query not working

Tags: php, sql

please give the resolution of these  why 
its not working print

```
$write=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtry(name,id) VALUES('$_POST['name']','')");}
```

it gives me an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dbtry.php on line 11

Comment: You got problem with quotes there. And with sql injections as well

Comment: First of all **Stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* functions which are deprecated, and please don't place input vars directly into a sql query - this leaves you wide open to sql injection. Look into mysqli_* functions or PDO :)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent an [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), I would advise to do the following:

```
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO dbtry(name,id) VALUES(?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Finally an answer that doesn't use the old and deprecated mysql* +1

Answer (score 0):

You should store value in a variable and

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$write=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtry(name,id) VALUES('$name','')");
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenate  operator(.) for POST values.

```
$write=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtry(name,id) VALUES('".$_POST['name']."','')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$write=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtry(name,id) VALUES('$_POST['name']','')");
```

to

```
$write = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO " .
    "dbtry (name,id) " .
    "VALUES ( " .
    "'" . $_POST['name'] . "' " .
    ",'' " .
    ")"
);
```